# Google Stackdriver Profling: How to understand this profile

Tags: google-app-engine, jvm, profiling, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

[image: Wall Time]
[image: CPU Time]
I have attached two Google Stackdriver Profilers for our backend server.
The backend api simply trying to read from Memcache first, if it doesn't exist or has timeout error, then retrieve the data from Big Table.

Based on the wall time and CPU time profiles, I'd like to know

1. Why the libjvm_so process consumes that much (45.8%) of CPU time, is it because the server allocates lots of memory that cause garbage collection using a lot of CPU?
2. The wall time profile shows 97% of thread time is waiting for a resource, I guess it's waiting for Memcache/big table server to return the data, is it true? Does this mean the server doesn't need that much CPU? (currently 16 CPUs, with an average load of 35%)
3. Any other insights? Where can be improved etc?

Comment: If you build your jvm from source, you can get debug symbols in libjvm.so, which will  let you see what is taking all that time. It is possible that all that time spent in libjvm.so is something like array copies(Many native methods like System.arrayCopy, are implemented in libjvm.so ).

Comment: libjvm.so could also be spending time waiting for IO

Comment: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild provides prebuilt jdk debug builds

Comment: To answer the part about garbage collection, you could use a java profiler like visualvm to tell you how much time is spent in garbage collection.